# Issue with div tags

Tags: html, tags

I am trying to work with divs instead of tables and am having some difficulty.

Here is my link...
http://www.dgssi.com/new-humbertown/

Could someone give me some help with this?

Thanks.

Comment: what's the exact problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the content to center in the page use this on #main_container:

```
margin:0px auto;
```

I am not sure what align:center does, but the above CSS will work for you.  HTH